# Regex works strange in Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

This is part of Scrapy parser function, in loop i am extracting text and searching for some string in text. 
This code finds random items, i mean it parse but when i check manually there is no matchings in text - very strange, because if no match it should not go inside "if" and append it:

```
for site in set(sites):
    if (re.findall(r'(Обам*)', " ".join(site.xpath('div/div/div').extract()), re.IGNORECASE)) !=None:
        item['Target'] = unicode('Obama')
        item['Label'] = unicode(" ".join(site.xpath('h3/a').extract()))
        items.append(item)
```

When i use another approach

```
len(re.search(r'(Обам*)', " ".join(site.xpath('div/div/div').extract()), re.IGNORECASE)) !=0:
```

it simply doesn't work at all, no any parsed items, but i am sure it should find. If i remove "len" counting - it start work, but again randomly (!!!).

By the way if i use simple string function string.find() it works fine.

Edit:
This is example Input (it's hard to exactly math input and output so this is some illusrating text, what is worth is that in that text no "Обама" but it saved with match Obama, "Target" : "Obama",):

```
<div class=\"b-text NahodkiStore-snippet\">\r\n\r\nОни оскорбили <b>Царева</b> не как частного человека, а как выразителя идей Юго-Востока.</div> <div class=\"b-text\"><div>Они оскорбили <b>Клинтон</b>\r\n не как частного человека, а как выразителя идей Юго-Востока. Они ясно \r\nдали понять, какое будущее они готовят русским на Украине.</div>
```

Output form MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("538fa13abb88b114143d750b"),
    "comment_datesaved" : ISODate("2014-06-05T02:44:01.749Z"),
    "comment_text" : "<div class=\"b-text NahodkiStore-snippet\">\r\n\r\nОни оскорбили <b>Царева</b> не как частного человека, а как выразителя идей Юго-Востока.</div> <div class=\"b-text\"><div>Они оскорбили <b>Обаму</b>\r\n не как частного человека, а как выразителя идей Юго-Востока. Они ясно \r\nдали понять, какое будущее они готовят русским на Украине.</div>",
    "Target" : "Obama",
    "Label" : "<a href=\"http://mikle1.livejournal.com/3907742.html?thread=42077854\" class=\"NahodkiStore-link SearchStatistics-link\" target=\"_blank\">\r\n\r\nОни оскорбили <b>Царева</b> не как частного человека, а как выразителя идей Юго-Востока.</a>",

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your input and your output?

Comment: Just to be safe, I suggest you use Unicode regular expressions: `re.search(ur'(Обам*)', " ".join(site.xpath('div/div/div').extract()), re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE)`

Comment: @paultrmbrth - YES, it start working!, i think it is common Python 2.7 problem with encoding of non english characters

Answer (score 3):

```
In [38]: import re

In [39]: s = "a string"

In [40]: re.findall("hello", s)== []
Out[40]: True

In [41]: re.findall("hello", s)==None
Out[41]: False
In [42]: re.findall("hello", s) != None
Out[42]: True

In [43]: re.findall("hello", s) 
Out[43]: []

re.findall returns an empty list not None
```

You should use:

```
 `if (re.findall(r'(Обам*)', " ".join(site.xpath('div/div/div').extract()),re.IGNORECASE))`.
```

Drop the `!= None` or you will always execute the code after the if statement.

```
In [49]: if re.findall("hello", s ):
             print ("found")
....:     

In [48]: if not re.findall("hello",s):
         print ("not found")
....:     
not found
```

The same is for re.search except it does return None if it finds no match but you should still just use `if re.search(....` without any `== or !=` :

```
In [64]: re.search("hello", s)!=0
Out[64]: True

In [65]: re.search("hello", s)==0
Out[65]: False

In [66]: re.search("hello", s)==None
Out[66]: True
```

Using `len` on a search that returns `None` will give you a `TypeError` `object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

If your strings are unicode you could specify a list of words and check if they are in your string.

```
words=[u'Обам' , u'Путин' ,u'OBAMA']
for word in  words:
    if re.search(word.encode("utf-8"), "".join(site.xpath('div/div/div').extract()))):
```

Comment: Did you mean to use the string literal `"s"`, rather than the variable `s` here?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the problem is that i have started from this simple if re.search(r'(Тягнибок*)|(Тягныбок*)', " ".join(site.xpath('div/div/div').extract()), re.IGNORECASE):  and now checked - it still don't parse anything. The more strange that i have another code without Scrapy with loop and reges search in file - and this code works. Of course i copied it analogically so - dont know what to do

Comment: @PadraicCunningham by the way "in" statement doesnot work too - it works randomly, but when i replace it with .find('') it starts working
if "Обама" in " ".join(site.xpath('div/div/div').extract()):   - not work

Comment: what exactly do you want your regex to do?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - general task, if it finds matching surname case insensitive in text i want it to save additional info

Comment: what does your `" ".join(site.xpath('div/div/div').extract())` look like, add an example of that and I will show you how to find what you want

Comment: i have edited main post with example text - its a mess of html tags and Cyrillic text, so for every find i want to save additional attributes. I have several "if" to search several surnames, but i need to count repeated occurrences of the same surname as one.

Comment: do you want to check for separate words or can the words be substrings ? You need to show an example of what one of your " `".join(site.xpath('div/div/div').extract())` looks like just print it out in your code and post it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham in most cases it simple word. Once more: if unicode(" ".join(site.xpath('div/div/div').extract())).find(u'Обама' or u'Путин' or u'OBAMA') != -1:    - this does work and correct finds and saves data. I have installed regex package - it also dont work as re.